# Text and image side by side

Tags: html, css-float

Here is the full stripped-back code. Can anyone see why the image and the text to won't align? Any ideas?

```
Question edited
```

Here is the full stripped-back code. Can anyone see why the image and the text to won't align? Any ideas?

Here is the full stripped-back code. Can anyone see why the image and the text to won't align? Any ideas?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px;
}

.about {
  background-color: #2c0242;
  padding: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2, p, img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BMS</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="customise.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="about">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="bikedark" class="icondetails">
  </div>
  <!--all other content contained in comment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use <p> use an <a> instead

Comment: yeah, as @MrCoder said, use like this

  <a>text</a>

Comment: Why to use a instead of p??? And chilledMonkeyBrain you want h1 aligned with p and the image?

Comment: Float the `p` left and remove its initial margins.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcpfygpt/) - i literally just changed the <p> to <a> tag :D - it places the image next to 'text'

Comment: Swapping the p for a did nothing. Yes Bojan, I want the h2 and all the <p> text to appear side by side with an image

Comment: @MrCoder There's no indication in the question that the "text" should be an anchor, so why would you suggest swapping a `p` tag for an `a` tag? It makes no semantic sense. I realize that an anchor tag would be inline versus the block-level p tag, but that still doesn't get them next to the h2, which is also block-level.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach it to make all of them(h1, p) display: inline-block;

Or you can add float: left; to h1 and p

I also have aligned them in the middle, to remove it simply remove vertical-align: middle;

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px;
}
.about {
  background-color: #2c0242;
  padding: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;  
}
h2, p, img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bojan. Your code is working fine in codepen, but not on my project, so it looks like i'm off on a bug-hunt.

Comment: try a hard reload @chilledMonkeyBrain (in chrome that's ctrl + shift + R) as your browser may still be looking at the cached css file

Comment: Thanks MrCoder. It didn't help this time, but i'll remember that for future. I've stripped the html and css back to the minimum, but  it just won't align. I'm sure i'll kick myself when I find it.

Comment: @chilledMonkeyBrain If you show us your code maybe we can help :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski There's maybe 100 words contained in the <p></p> not sure if that's relevant or not...

Comment: You can add max-width to p and it will wrap the words, and it will be aligned :) I don't know exactly what are you trying to accomplish, maybe show an image of what is your goal :)

Comment: Simply trying to have the text and image side by side. The code you provided works great until there's more than one line of text, then the image drops under the text again. Isn't there a 'clear' to stop this from happening?

Comment: Never mind everyone. I got it. Needed to float image right, h2 p left a p clear both. Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to float image right, h2 p left a p clear both